How frequently does new relic alert queries into the new relic log data?
We have designed a new relic query for one alert which will notify to one of the slack channels if the threshold for the query is breached.
Expectation is:-
Let's say if any error log comes to new relic within 1 minute as per(Critical: Query result is above 0 for at least 1 minute), it should send the notification to slack channel.
So, expectation is:- new relic should query the logs every minute and check if the count of error log is above 0 for that minute then notify the same to slack channel.
Right now there is a confusion that how frequently does new relic executes the query that is configured for that specific alert. Will new relic send the alert every minute if the count is above 0 for the query?
select count(*) FROM Log where message LIKE '%error occurred%' OR message LIKE '%Failed to%'  AND message LIKE '%Dummy Job%'

